How to configure a forever running systemd service while being able to report for errors after a certain amount of attempts?
Desired Solution
I have a service that shall run indefinitely (self-healing) but shall report the occurred error to another resource in order to not create a zombie service which is constantly restarted without being notified.
Problematic Code
This is the my_infinite.service file. For demonstration purposes it will exit with code 1 after two seconds to simulate an error that occurred in the deamonized application. In this example the service shall report when two unsuccessful attempts occurred in 20 seconds:
#/etc/systemd/system/my_infinite.service
[Unit]
Description=self-healing service that shall run for ever.
After=network.target
OnFailure=failure-handler@%N.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=20s
StartLimitBurst=2

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/zsh -c "echo 'started' && sleep 2 && echo 'finished' && exit 1"
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s


The error handler looks like this. It (1) resets the error counter, (2) calls a custom script that does the (slack) reporting and (3) restarts the service:
#/etc/systemd/system/failure-handler@.service:

[Unit]
Description=My failure handler for %i

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=systemctl reset-failed %i && /usr/bin/report_service_error_to_slack.zsh %i && systemctl restart %i

From the logs you can see that the OnFailure event is triggered succesfully triggered before the third restart, because the restart limit is reached.
Mai 29 11:17:33 systemd[1]: Started self-healing service that shall run for ever..
Mai 29 11:17:33 zsh[202342]: started
Mai 29 11:17:35 zsh[202342]: finished
Mai 29 11:17:35 systemd[1]: my_infinite.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mai 29 11:17:35 systemd[1]: my_infinite.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mai 29 11:17:40 systemd[1]: my_infinite.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Mai 29 11:17:40 systemd[1]: Stopped self-healing service that shall run for ever..
Mai 29 11:17:40 systemd[1]: Started self-healing service that shall run for ever..
Mai 29 11:17:40 zsh[202351]: started
Mai 29 11:17:42 zsh[202351]: finished
Mai 29 11:17:42 systemd[1]: my_infinite.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mai 29 11:17:42 systemd[1]: my_infinite.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mai 29 11:17:47 systemd[1]: my_infinite.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Mai 29 11:17:47 systemd[1]: Stopped self-healing service that shall run for ever..
Mai 29 11:17:47 systemd[1]: my_infinite.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mai 29 11:17:47 systemd[1]: my_infinite.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mai 29 11:17:47 systemd[1]: Failed to start self-healing service that shall run for ever..
Mai 29 11:17:47 systemd[1]: my_infinite.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.

Problem
The problem with this code is, that the service is not restarted from the failure-handler. As can be seen from the logs.
My current workaround is to use StartLimitIntervalSec=0 in the Unit section combined with ExecStopPost=/bin/zsh -c 'if [ "$$EXIT_STATUS" != 0 ]; then systemctl start systemd-alert@%N.service; fi' in the Service section.
This feels like a hack. What is wrong my the original solution. Alternatively can one provide a working example to the original question: "How to configure a forever running systemd service while being able to report for errors to a 3rd party software e.g. Slack, Mail, etc?"

Figured out the problem. The ExecStart directive can not interpret multiple commands by concatenating it with &&. Realized that there must be a problem with the concatonating operator after seeing, that whatever I do only the first command was interpreted by ExecStart. The systemd service man page explicitly lists allowed meta-characters and expansions and state that

"other elements of shell syntax are not supported."

The syntax for concatenating commands is: " ; " which would be in my case: ExecStart=systemctl reset-failed %i ; /usr/bin/report_service_error_to_slack.zsh %i ; systemctl restart %i 
To make the template more readable I chose to specify the
ExecStart multiple times. The working solution looks like this
#/etc/systemd/system/failure-handler@.service:

[Unit]
Description=My failure handler for %i

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/report_service_error_to_slack.zsh %i
ExecStart=systemctl reset-failed %i
ExecStart=systemctl restart %i

Note that concatonating commands with " ; " and multiple ExecStart directives only work for oneshot service types!
Now the service reports to Slack after every second unsuccessful restart (within 20s). Works like a charm.
This way the service is back-up and running whenever possible while giving a chance to a sysadmin to react to the error message in case the service turns into a zombie because it is constantly restarting without solving the actual problem.
